# Instantiating non-type templated member function of a type-templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a header file with the following, say `temp.hh`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class MyClass
{
public:

    template <bool isTrue>
    void MyFunc(T1& t, T2 t2) const;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
template <bool isTrue>
void MyClass<T1,T2>::MyFunc(T1& t, T2 t2) const
{
    cout << t << " " << (int)t2 << " " << isTrue << endl;
}
```

Then another header file (`temp2.hh`) that only instantiates the function `MyFunc`:

```
#include "temp.hh"

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void TEST_OP2(MyClass<T1,T2> *mc)
{
    T1 a = 3;
    T2 b = 7;
    mc->MyFunc<false>(a, b);
}
```

In the main.cpp, I have the following:

```
#include "temp2.hh"

int main(void)
{
    MyClass<int, int8_t>* myclass = new MyClass<int, int8_t>();
    /* The following 3 commented lines compiles and runs fine,
       if I only include temp.hh */
    // int a = 3;
    // int8_t b = 7;
    // myclass->MyFunc<false>(a, b);
    TEST_OP2<int, int8_t>(myclass); // !! this fails to compile !!
}
```

The error is:

```
temp2.hh:8:9: reference to non-static member function must be called
    mc->MyFunc<false>(a, b);
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to properly do this if this is at all possible?

NOTE: As you can tell, this is just a sample code reproducing the issue I am having. In the actual project, for various reasons, I cannot have the full instantiation of `MyFunc` in the cpp file (like the commented codes in the `main.cpp` above).

EDIT:
Also, how to get a function pointer of MyFunc in temp2.hh?

ANSWER by @rafix07 are in the comments. Both of the approaches work as shown below.

```
#include "temp.hh"

// The following 2 lines are needed only for the second approach
template<class T11,class T22>
using PtrMem = void (MyClass<T11,T22>::*)(T11&,T22) const;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void TEST_OP2(MyClass<T1,T2> *mc)
{
    T1 a = 3;
    T2 b = 7;
    // The following 3 lines show how the first approach works
    // typedef void (MyClass<T1,T2>::*ptrMem)(T1&,T2) const; 
    // ptrMem pmem = &MyClass<T1,T2>::template MyFunc<false>; 
    // (mc->*pmem)(a,b);

    // The following 2 lines show how the second approach works
    PtrMem<T1,T2> pmem = &MyClass<T1,T2>::template MyFunc<false>;
    (mc->*pmem)(a,b);
}
```

Comment: Avoid `using namespace` in header.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Good to know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mc` is dependent name, you need to use `template` when you want to call templated method on `mc`:

```
mc->template MyFunc<false>(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I will mark it as the answer as soon as SO allows. A follow up question: if I need a pointer to the function MyFunc in temp2.hh, do you know how to do that?

Comment: You can try something like this `typedef void (MyClass<T1,T2>::*ptrMem)(T1&,T2) const;   ptrMem pmem = &MyClass<T1,T2>::template MyFunc<false>; (mc->*pmem)(a,b);`. All this code is in `TEST_OP2` function.

Comment: @rakib the "ask wuestion" button is for asking wuestions, the "add comment" button is for clarifications.  Ask a different question, or search for "pointer to template member function".  A comment q&a will be brief, incomplete and misleading; such as rafix's comment above.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, Thanks. I wasn't sure how I should've asked the question. I guess I can just edit my original post with the second question and rafix07's answer if it works for me. Will that be alright?

Comment: @Rakib Instead of local typedef, you can use alias template `template<class T1,class T2> using PtrMem = void (MyClass<T1,T2>::*)(T1&,T2) const;` then you create `pmem` as `PtrMem<T1,T2> pmem = &MyClass<T1,T2>::template MyFunc<false>;`.

Comment: @rafix07 Thanks for the replies. The first approach worked fine but not the second one. The error : expected expression (at the beginning of the template keyword).

Comment: @Rakib Check this link https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33d8d7ad54b2a5cb works fine.

Comment: @rafix07 Ah, sorry. Made a typo. It's working now. Is one approach better than the other? I mean in terms of performance.

Comment: @rakid no, just hit `ask question`.  Rafix may be helping, but (a) they shouldn't be here, (b) you are probably asking an X/Y question (the wrong question to fix your actual problem).  Don't edit in a second question, don't continue asking questions in comments.  Nobody is checking Rafix's answer down here, your question is fragmented, nobody etc.  And this Q&A is going to be deleted, because that is what hapoens to comments.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I am not sure I understand the problem here. The second question is in the same context (same sample code and everything). If I create a new post to just to ask a deeply related question, won't that be redundant?